# Induced Radon Measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is problem 7.1 from Folland's Real Analysis:

> Let $X$ be an LCH space, $Y$ a closed subset of $X$, and $\mu$ a Radon Measure on $Y$. Then $I(f) = \int f|_Y d\mu$ is a positive linaer functional on $C_c(X)$, and the induced Radon measure $\nu$ on $X$ is given by $\nu(E) = \mu (E \cap Y)$.

Our professor told us that for clarity, $E \subset \mathbb{B}_X$ (the smallest sigma-algebra containing all open sets of a topology). I was able to show that $I$ is a positive linear functional. However, I don't understand what it's asking me to do for the second part. What's an "induced" Radon measure? I already know $\mu$ is a Radon measure, so I'm not sure what we're supposed to do.

Comment: Since $I$ is a positive linear functional, according to the Riesz representation theorem there is a corresponding Radon measure $\nu$.

Comment: @carmichael561 So since $I$ is a positive linear functional, then by Riesz, there is a unique measure $\nu$ so that $I(f) = \int f d\nu$, and I'm trying to show that the relationship between $\nu$ and $\mu$ is defined above?

Comment: That's correct.